# How to generate base62 UUIDs in node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, uuid, base62

I'm looking for a solution to generate base62 UUIDs in node.js. I'd like to avoid base64 as I intend to create folders based on these UUIDs and characters like `=`, `\`, `-`, `_` (as in some implementations) are not that human/filesystem friendly.

Base62 also has the advantage (in my context) of being shorter than a typical v4 UUID.

**UPDATE** (for clarity): I should have said earlier that I already tried using `base62` module but this doesn't solve my issue since `base62` takes numbers in javascript integer numbers are only precise up to 52 bits while UUIDs have 128.

Comment: [`base-x`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base-x) seems to be a good option to use with [`uuid`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid)'s support for Buffers. The trade-off is that you'll have to specify the character range for base62 as it doesn't have any predefined.

Comment: It does indeed, not sure how I missed it when I searched, thanks Jonathan! In the meantime I've started working on a solution of my own, I'll compare both when I'm done.

Comment: I've just compared `b62` against `base-x` and `base-x` is way faster than what I was doing.

Comment: Forgot the gist link: [b62.vs.base-x.js](https://gist.github.com/dmarcelino/879d4da2a0e0c32f7d74).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is a comprehensive answer:

### Solution A: `base-x` + `node-uuid`

*Inspired by @Jonathan's earlier comment.*

Use [node-uuid](https://github.com/broofa/node-uuid) to generate the UUID and then encode it with [base-x](https://github.com/dcousens/base-x):

```
var buf = new Buffer(16);
var uuid = Uuid.v4(null, buf);
var uuidB62 = baseX.encode(uuid);
// -> 71jbvv7LfRKYp19gtRLtkn
```

`base-x` is very fast so this is the most performant solution.

### Solution B: [`uuid-base62`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid-base62)

Before knowing about `base-x` I went ahead and created a module for the base62 encoding ([b62](https://github.com/dmarcelino/b62)) and another for the base62 UUID generation: [uuid-base62](https://github.com/dmarcelino/uuid-base62):

```
var uuidB62 = uuidBase62.v4();  // -> 2qY9COoAhfMrsH7mCyh86T
```

This is the *no frills* solution. <del>Currently it's not as fast as A since `b62` is much slower but I intend to replace it with `base-x`.</del>

**UPDATE:** `uuid-base62` has been updated to use `base-x`.

Comment: `uuid-base62` has been updated to use `base-x` in v0.1.0, so it no longer has the performance penalty it used to have.

Comment: Could you please update your answer? I'd like to try out your answer but using Buffer constructor is deprecated and `node-uuid` has been replaced by `uuid` package.

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATE**: The module I originally pointed out is for converting base 62 numbers to base 10 and vice versa, so that won't do. Looks like original poster is creating their own module to do this: https://github.com/dmarcelino/b62

There is [a base62 module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base62) that you can use. Here is their sample code:

```
Base62 = require('base62')
Base62.encode(999)  // 'g7' 
Base62.decode('g7') // 999
```

The module can be installed with `npm install base62`. To have it as a dependency in your `package.json`, use `npm install --save base62` instead.

Comment: Note: The module appears to only support encoding numbers and the size of UUIDs exceeds the possible precision.

Comment: Yes, precisely Jonathan.

Comment: Whoops, sorry about that. Well, there's always the node module the original poster is creating: https://github.com/dmarcelino/b62 Updated the answer to include that, but I guess that's not much of an answer.

Comment: No worries. Yes, I've started working on it after searching and not finding a solution... I'll post my results once I achieve what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution for those using Node.js 16+ with just `base-x` as a dependency:

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const BASE62 = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
const base62 = require('base-x')(BASE62);

function generateBase62UUID() {
  const uuid = crypto.randomUUID();
  const buf = Buffer.from(uuid, 'utf-8');
  return base62.encode(buf);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Install packages:

```sh
npm install uuid
npm install base-x
```

Generate identifier:

```js
const uuid = require('uuid')
const base62 = require('base-x')('0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ')

const id = base62.encode(Buffer.from(uuid.parse(uuid.v4())))
```

Answer (score -1):

npm install base62x

```
var base62x = require('base62x');

var encoded = base62x.encode('hello');
var decodedBuffer = base62x.decode(encoded);
var decodedString = base62x.decodeString(encoded);
```

Base62x.class.js is another option for this question. See https://github.com/wadelau/Base62x , https://www.npmjs.com/package/base62x for more information.